# ctypes dll declaration of variables

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I'm trying to use following function with ctypes and I do have troubles how declare all the parameters and variables right.

The Documentation of the C code is following,

```
/* global variables */

int main ()

char sDeviceSerialNumber[32];

FEUSB_GetScanListPara( 0, "Device-ID", sDeviceSerialNumber ) ;
```

sDeviceSerialNumber is supposed to be a return value of the function which I need in Python for further use.

Python code:

```
def FEUSB_GetScanListPara(iIndex, cPara):
    libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, 
                                               ctypes.c_wchar_p,                                                  
                                    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)
                                              ]
  
    libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara.restype = ctypes.c_int
    
    iIndex = ctypes.c_int(iIndex)
    cValue_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(32)
    cValue = ctypes.c_char_p(ctypes.addressof(cValue_buffer))

    value = libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara(iIndex, 
                                           cPara,                                      
                                           ctypes.byref(cValue)
                                           )

if __name__ == "__main__":
   i = 0
   RFID.FEUSB_GetScanListPara(i, "Device-ID")
```

When I call the function with the code above, I get an error code, FEUSB_ERR_UNKNOWN_PARAMETER, therefore I assume that I do not declare the parameters correctly.

Any input is appreciated!

#### EDIT 1

```
    def FEUSB_GetScanListPara(iIndex, cPara):
        libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, 
                                                   ctypes.c_char_p,
                                                   ctypes.c_char_p
                                                
                                                  ]
        libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara.restype = ctypes.c_int  
        cValue = ctypes.create_string_buffer(32)
        value = libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara(iIndex, cPara, 
                                               ctypes.byref(cValue))

        print("1.0", cPara, "back value", " = ", value)
        print("1.1", cPara, " = ", cValue.value)

        print("######")

if __name__ == "__main__":

   data = RFID.FEUSB_GetScanListPara(i, b"Device-ID")
```

Python Console:

```
FEUSB_ClearScanList =  0
FEUSB_Scan =  0
FEUSB_GetScanListSize =  1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\xxxxx\3.1_ObidRFID_test\OBID_RFID_06.py", line 265, in <module>
    data = RFID.FEUSB_GetScanListPara(i, b"Device-ID")

  File "C:\xxxxx\3.1_ObidRFID_test\OBID_RFID_06.py", line 89, in FEUSB_GetScanListPara
    value = libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara(iIndex, cPara, ctypes.byref(cValue))

ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

#### EDIT 2

working code

```
    def FEUSB_GetScanListPara(iIndex, cPara):
        libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, 
                                                   ctypes.c_char_p,
                                                   ctypes.c_char_p
                                                   ]
                                                
        libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara.restype = ctypes.c_int                                          
        cValue = ctypes.create_string_buffer(32)
        
        return_value = libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara(0, b'Device-ID', 
                                                      cValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `.argtypes` would match the C prototype of:

```
int FEUSB_GetScanListPara(int, wchar_t*, char**)
```

You haven't provided the exact C prototype, but from your example of:

```
FEUSB_GetScanListPara( 0, "Device-ID", sDeviceSerialNumber ) ;
```

and knowing `wchar_t*` is not a common interface parameter, you probably actually have simple `char*` declarations like:

```
int FEUSB_GetScanListPara(int, const char*, char*);
```

I'm assuming the 2nd parameter is an input parameter and 3rd parameter is an output parameter.  Note that `c_char_p` corresponds to a byte string so use `b'DeviceID'` for `cPara`.  Also if you have to allocate the buffer, the 3rd parameter is unlikely to be `char**`.  If the API itself is not returning a pointer, but filling out an already allocated buffer, `char*` and hence `ctypes.c_char_p` is appropriate.  You correctly use `create_string_buffer()` for an output parameter.

Note you don't need to wrap `iIndex` in a `c_int`.  From `.argtypes`, `ctypes` knows the 1st parameter is a `c_int` and converts it for you.  That's also the default if no `.argtypes` is provided, but better to be explicit and provide `.argtypes`.

This code should work.  I don't have the DLL to verify:

```py
import ctypes as ct

libfeusb = CDLL('./FESUB') # assuming in same directory
libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara.argtypes = ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p, ct.c_char_p
libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara.restype = ct.c_int
cValue = ct.create_string_buffer(32)
ret = libfeusb.FEUSB_GetScanListPara(0, b'Device-ID', cValue)
if ret == 0:
    print(cValue.value)
else:
    print('error:',ret)
```

If you still have issues, edit your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Make sure to provide the real C prototype.

Comment: @name_not_available I'm just guessing without seeing the C prototype of the function you are trying to call.  If you make a [mcve] that produces the error that will be very helpful.  It can also help to make a working version with C as an example of correct use, and then port that to Python.  Step 1 is getting `.argtypes` and `.restype` to match the function you are calling, then `wrong type` indicates that passing the parameters correctly is the problem.

Comment: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00275180-developing-an-application-allowing-pr101usb-and-mr101usb-feig-readers-to-communicate-with-m24lrxx-transponders-stmicroelectronics.pdf. I'm trying to call the function at the above documentation page 17.

Comment: @name_not_available You should edit your question with the prototype and C example, but from the doc link my guess was correct and you need the code above.  Show your exact code (edit the question) that reproduces the problem.  Do you know that `cValue.value` is need to read the returned string?  I edited my answer to what I think you need based on the link.

Comment: it works.... many thanks!!

Comment: @name_not_available Great!  Be sure to upvote and select as the correct answer then 